# How does Google handle relative _escaped_fragment_ URL-s?

Tags: ajax, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I'm trying to understand Google AJAX-crawling.

Say, I have an HTML page like this at `example.com`:

```
<title>My Page</title>
<a href="#!foo=bar">Some link</a>
```

When crawling the `#!foo=bar` link, google will fetch `example.com?_escaped_fragment=foo=bar`.  As a response to this I will serve the following HTML:

```
<title>My Other Page</title>
<a href="#!blah=zap">Another link</a>
```

Now the question is, what will Google think of the `#!blah=zap` link? I see two possibilities:

- Google will treat the URL as `example.com?_escaped_fragment=blah=zap` and will successfully fetch the page.
- Google will see that this relative URL really resolves to `example.com?_escaped_fragment=foo=bar#!blah=zap` and will fail to fetch the page I want him to.

So which way might it be?

**PS.** Is there some way to test this? I've been using the "Fetch as Google" service, but it doesn't tell me how it will crawl the links it finds on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check : [Full specification of _escaped_fragment_](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) ?

Regarding your question, I'll suggest that Google will interpret as : "Google will treat the URL as example.com?_escaped_fragment=blah=zap and will successfully fetch the page."

Comment: OK. Thanks. After digesting all this again, my reasoning goes that at the worst case Google would translate the URL to `example.com?_escaped_fragment_=something&_escaped_fragment_=somethingElse` where the second parameter would override the first one, leaving us with `example.com?_escaped_fragment_=somethingElse`, meaning that my link would definitely work. So thanks for taking the time to answer.